# How To Install GEOS for GeoDjango on Windows

Tags: windows, django, installation, geodjango, geos

I'm starting a GeoDjango project using Python 2.5, Django 1.2, MySQL and Apache. The project will be uploaded to a Linux server but the development will be on a Windows.

The problem is I just can't get passed installing GEOS, how is it done?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I follow the instructions in

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/install/#windows

For the instalation of GEOS library in windows i use this:

http://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/

Comment: I've already tried using the installer. I get an error at : `from django.contrib.gis.db import models`. The error is :  `ImportError: Could not find the GEOS library (tried "geos_c"). Try setting GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH in your settings` so I set the GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH to where i installed GeoDjango in `D:\Python25\Lib\site-packages\GeoDjango` now I get `The specified module cannot be found`

Comment: put the dll in your project directory and GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH in the settings.

Comment: Could it be because I'm using Python 2.5? Django doucumentation indicates it should be 2.7

Comment: i dont think so. i was using python 2.5

Answer (score 5):

what I did is to install GDAL from this answer, [Unable to install Python and GDAL (DLL load failed)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6009506/unable-to-install-python-and-gdal-dll-load-failed), and then add this line to `settings.py`,

```
GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH = 'C:/Program Files/GDAL/geos_c.dll'
```

then it is fine to use postgis.

Comment: No idea why but this is the only solution that worked for me after searching the whole Stack Overflow! With `geos_c.dll` in the `GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH` (I have `GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH = C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\geos_c.dll`). Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Follow this tutorial it will Install GDAL complete library including GEOS.
Just did it yesterday worked fine

http://www.gis.usu.edu/~chrisg/python/2009/docs/gdal_win.pdf

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to use with my Ubuntu:

```
 sudo apt-get install gdal-bin
```